# No login shell with Vagrant SSH command

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, shell, vagrant

When running a virtual Ubuntu machine with Vagrant, there's something strange going on with the shell after I log in via SSH:

```
➜  dev-environment git:(master) vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-123-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Fri Jul  7 20:19:57 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.97              Processes:           81
  Usage of /:   3.6% of 39.34GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 6%                IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
# cursor starts here on a blank line
```

If I look for what shell it has logged me in to:

```
echo $0
-bash
```

I can continue to use the command line, but it seems really strange that there is not a typical prompt character at the beginning of a line when bash is waiting for a command, e.g., `$` or `#`.

Context:

```
➜  dev-environment git:(master) vagrant version
Installed Version: 1.9.6
```

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.box_version = "<20170602" # Latest prior to June 2, 2017

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
  end

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
  config.vm.hostname = "dev-server"

  # Create a swapfile
  config.vm.provision "shell", name: "swapfile creation", path: "create-swap.sh"

  # Get ready
  config.vm.provision "shell", name: "key setup", inline: <<-SHELL
    ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
    su - vagrant -c 'ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""'
  SHELL

  # Install docker and nginx
  config.vm.provision "shell", name: "docker install", inline: <<-SHELL
    curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
    curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.13.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  SHELL

  # Set up server for the first time
  config.vm.provision "shell", name: "server startup", inline: <<-SHELL
    cd /vagrant/dev-server
    LOCAL_DEV_ENVIRONMENT=true ./generate-docker-compose.sh
    docker-compose up -d
  SHELL
end
```

Bash startup scripts (added back `$` for clarity):

```
$ ls -la ~
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul 10 17:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4096 Jul 10 17:35 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  220 Apr  9  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 3637 Apr  9  2014 .bashrc
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul 10 17:35 .cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  675 Apr  9  2014 .profile
drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul 10 17:35 .ssh


$ cat .profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi


$ cat .bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Any thoughts on why bash looks so strange after login?

Comment: Sounds like the virtual Ubuntu machine doesn't have a script that initializes the prompt. Does it have a .profile or .bashrc file?

Comment: Added `.profile` and `.bashrc` to check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading to [Vagrant 1.9.7](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/compare/v1.9.6...v1.9.7).